# Is there a way to have the OS turn off some monitors but leave others on?

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors

I have some monitors that I like to leave on for monitoring sakes. Others, I would like to sleep to not waste power.

Is there a way to do this within Windows? So far I've not found a way to do.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, Windows does not have the ability to set specific monitors to sleep.

The best alternatives I can give you are to:

- Change your display settings to only show windows on the monitors you want (Which, if you are doing regularly, could become tedious and/or tiresome)
- Turn off the monitors you don't want on by their power button. (This is also the most power efficient method)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is *no* equivalent of the `IPMI` protocol for monitors.

But, there are intelligent remote power strips you can buy that can be controlled via USB/Ethernet [and even RS/232].

They allow a computer to turn the individual sockets on/off at will. They sometimes come with software. But, in any case, the protocol is usually very simple and can often be controlled via a telnet connection.

You'll just have to shop around to find one with the number of output sockets you need and one that matches your budget. They can be ~$100+, the more expensive models support more A/C sockets.

I've also seen some DIY models based on a Rasberry PI